# C# Argument out of Range while sending mail

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Sometimes, using the following code :

```
  return SmtpClient.Send(message, OutboundClient.Host, OutboundClient.Port);
```

I retrieve the following error :

```
 ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count cannot be less than zero.Parameter name:count
      at System.String.RemoveInternal(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count)
      at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.TraceInfo.ToString()
      at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Header.ToHeaderString(Boolean removeBlindCopies)
      at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message.ToMimeString(Boolean removeBlindCopies)
      at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message.ToMimeString()
      at ActiveUp.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(Message message, String host, Int32 port)
```

In my code Host and Port are static values that never change message instead is (Message object) readen in another mailbox (but i have checked is always valorized even if this exception is thrown)

Anyone know why sometimes i get the exception above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your version of MailSystem.NET.

[There was a bug](https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/workitem/24007) that look like yours on versions prior to 71651.

It happens when `From`, `By`, `With`, `For`, `Via` and `Id` are all empty.

Comment: thanks a lot i use the version 5.0 and probabily the cause is that bug

Comment: Another question, where can i download the latest vesion of MailSystem.NET?
The version that i actually use is the last released on codeplex (version 5.0.3454.364), so where can i download the revision #71651 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you got the May 2013 Release, you can try dev version from here: https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets or open a bug here: https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.